# Some Windows servers do not seem to have RSA certificates. What is wrong?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, rsa, windows, powershell

Some Windows Server 2012 machines have certificates.  Some do not.

I am running this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrenterUser\My | 
Where-Object {  $_.PrivateKey -is [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider] -and $_.NotBefore -lt (Get-Date) -and $_.NotAfter -gt (Get-Date) }
```

When it finds nothing, what is the easiest way to create a certificate?

I know responders do not know about my environment.  But these Windows Server 2012 machines are identical for the most part.  I can open PowerShell as Administrator, and I still can find no certificates on some machines.  If you have a theory as to why some servers have one or more results and others have none, please tell me.

Comment: this is a Windows Server question and not a general security question

Comment: Why do you need them?

Comment: I want to decrypt files encrypted on different servers.  With an RSA key from one server, I can decrypt on a second server a file encrypted on the first server.